# How to rewrite code using stream and optional

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I'm trying to rewrite code with nested conditions using Optional and Stream. That's how he looked:

```
if (transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION") != null) {
    editObj = (EmployeeWorkstation) transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION");
} else {
    if (editObj != null) {
        editObj = editObj.getEditInstance(transaction);
    } else {
        editObj = HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId);
    }
}
```

I tried to rewrite so:

```
editObj =
    ofNullable(
        (EmployeeWorkstation) transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION"))
        .orElse(
            editObj != null
                ? editObj.getEditInstance(transaction)
                : HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId));
```

And it works fine but my mentor said that it can be simplified

then I tried so:

```
editObj =
    Optional.ofNullable(
        (EmployeeWorkstation) transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION"))
            .map(obj -> obj.getEditInstance(transaction))
            .orElse(HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId));
```

I understand that my .map() does not work as described above in the first versions. How can I rewrite .map so that it works as described above?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Do you get an error? Do you get unexpected results?

Comment: I always get HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId)

Comment: One difference is that if `obj.getEditInstance(transaction)` returns null inside `map`, then you will get `HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId)`.

Comment: However I should get `editObj.getEditInstance(transaction)` if `editObj != null`. And I don't have ideas how to process this condition at map.

Comment: call me weird. i prefer the old java code. also, it will be faster.

Comment: @aran when code is highly conditional, streams are definitely not *my* friend. But that's a personal opinion. I'm not so sure what yeapp is thinking to optimise, it does not necessarily have to be execution speed.

Comment: `editObj = ofNullable( (EmployeeWorkstation) 
 transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION"))  .orElseGet(() -> ofNullable(editObj).map(o -> o.getEditInstance(transaction)) .orElse(HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId)));` but I wouldn’t use an `Optional` at all.

Comment: Do not use Optional as a replacement for if/else.  That’s not what Optional is for.

Comment: @Gimby yep, agreed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
EmployeeWorkstation edit = Optional.ofNullable((EmployeeWorkstation) transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION"))
        .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(editObj)
                .map(e -> e.getEditInstance(transaction))
                .orElseGet(() -> HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId)));
```

If you are using Java 9 or higher you can use [`Optional.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
EmployeeWorkstation edit = Optional.ofNullable((EmployeeWorkstation) transaction.getObjectByName("EDIT_EMPLOYEE_WORKSTATION"))
        .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(editObj).map(edit -> edit.getEditInstance(transaction)))
        .orElseGet(() -> HOME.newEmployeeWorkstation(compId));
```